# How to align derived class members such that the first member comes immediately after the last member of the base class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, alignment, memory-alignment

To start with, I'm using VC++ 2015 U3 and I am looking for an answer that is specific to that compiler.

I have a struct that has a `char data[1]` as its last member, which is a placeholder for embedded data.  I'd like to make it cleaner to just derive a template struct from that which takes a `size_t` indicating how much data is after it.  Like so:

```
// This is a placeholder for any WINAPI structs that has this form
struct base_struct
{
  DWORD stuff;
  char data[1];
};

template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct my_struct : base_struct
{
  char rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - 1];
};
```

However, there is an alignment issue.  The `rest_of_data` is located 4 bytes away from `data` of the base class.  This is annoying.  I've tried to use [`#pragma pack(push,1)`/`#pragma pack(pop)`, `__declspec(align(1))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx), but I can't seem to get the derived data to immediately follow the base data.

Perhaps I'm not using them correctly?  Is there a way of doing this?

P.S., I already know I can do a lot of tricks to manage the memory and use `reinterpret_cast`, but I would like to see if this is a viable option first.

P.P.S.  `base_struct` is not my struct.  It is any number of struct that are part of the `WINAPI`.  It is not up to me to update or modify it, that is why I am attempting to make something that I can build on top of the already defined structs for.

## EDIT

I've attempted using the has-a rather than the is-a relationship, and I got something odd happening.  `offsetof()` is saying that the position is correct, but when I get the actual address position, it is aligned. *sigh*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define report_success(x) (!(x) ? (void)0 : (void)(std::cout << #x << std::endl))
int main()
{
    struct old_t
    {
        DWORD                      stuff;
        CHAR                       data[1];
    };
    struct new_t
    {
        old_t __declspec(align(1)) internal;
        char  __declspec(align(1)) extended_data[1];
    };
    new_t x;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// padded //////////// not padded /////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// should | actually || should | actually //
    report_success(offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 0);   //   T   |     T    ||    T   |     T    //
    report_success(offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 1);   //   F   |     F    ||    F   |     F    //
    report_success(offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 2);   //   F   |     F    ||    F   |     F    //
    report_success(offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 3);   //   F   |     F    ||    F   |     F    //
    report_success(&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[1]);            //   T   |     F    ||    T   |     F    //
    report_success(&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[2]);            //   F   |     F    ||    F   |     F    //
    report_success(&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[3]);            //   F   |     F    ||    F   |     F    //
    report_success(&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[4]);            //   F   |     T    ||    F   |     T    //
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 0
&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[1]
```

Actual output:

```
offsetof(new_t, extended_data) == sizeof(old_t) + 0
&x.extended_data[0] == &x.internal.data[4]
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/SMZZF50497)</kbd>

Comment: Why not just shadow the element in the base class?  Are you trying to match some specific binary format?

Comment: @stark, what do you mean by shadow the element in the base class?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so you are saying use a has-a rather than a is-a relationship?  I'll give that a go.

Comment: @Adrian: Your `old_t` struct itself is not byte-aligned, you are only byte-aligning the `internal` member of `new_t`. You are not taking into account that the compiler may be adding padding between `stuff` and `data`, or more likely adding padding after `data` to align the total size of `old_t`. So, `sizeof(old_t)` is likely not 5 like you are expecting, it may actually be 8+ instead, depending on the actual alignment. That extra padding would throw off your `&extended.data[x] == &internal.data[y]` calculations without affecting your `offsetof` calculations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Hmmm, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't do what you are asking for.  The compiler is free to insert padding between `base_struct` and `my_struct` as it sees fit, and you can't tell it not to do so.

If you are going to use templates anyway, consider passing a template parameter to specify the desired type of `data`, instead of using `char[1]`, eg:

```
template <typename T>
struct base_struct
{
    ...
    T data;
};
```

And then define types for `data` to use, eg:

```
template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct data_buffer
{
    char buffer[DATA_SIZE];
};
```

Or, in C++11 and later:

```
template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
using data_buffer = char[DATA_SIZE];
```

Then you can use `base_struct<data_buffer<...> >`, eg:

```
template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct my_struct : base_struct<data_buffer<DATA_SIZE> >
{
};
```

Or, at the very least, specify the full size of `base_struct::data[]` as a template parameter:

```
template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct base_struct
{
    ...
    char data[DATA_SIZE];
};

template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct my_struct : base_struct<DATA_SIZE>
{
};
```

---

**UPDATE**:

> `base_struct` is not my struct. It is any number of struct that are part of the `WINAPI`

In that case, consider using a approach similar to [`NMHDR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775514.aspx) and its descendants ([`NMLISTVIEW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774773.aspx), [`NMTREEVIEW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773411.aspx), etc). Instead of *deriving* `my_struct` from `base_struct`, have `my_struct` *contain* a `base_struct` member.  Then you can byte-align an additional data member up against the end of the `base_struct` member:

```
struct win32_struct
{
  DWORD stuff;
  char data[1];
};

#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <size_t DATA_SIZE>
struct my_struct
{
  win32_struct base;
  char rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - (sizeof(win32_struct) - offsetof(win32_struct, data))];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Not my class to modify.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that already.  That is why I posted this question.  `data` and `rest_of_data` are still not contiguous memory locations. :(  Also, your calculation `DATA_SIZE - sizeof(win32_struct)` is wrong.

Comment: ... unless you are referring to the actual size of the entire data structure, but then you've introduced a potential -ve value as a dimension which will either cause an error or potentially a very large array.  This is also not as easy to understand as just specifying the size of the end array.

Comment: I clarified in my 2nd comment.  It depends on what your `DATA_SIZE` is representing.  You appear to be representing the size of the entire structure, including the additional text.

Comment: @Adrian: That is what your original code in your question is doing. `DATA_SIZE` is the full byte size of the derived struct data, including the base and derived fields together.

Comment: Sorry, no. `rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - 1]` is the size of the data - 1 character as it was already allocated in the base class.

Comment: @Adrian that is exactly what I said in my last comment. Since `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and `DATA_SIZE` wants the combined size of the two fields acting together

Comment: Um, what comment are you referring to?  You said in the answer you gave `rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - sizeof(win32_struct)]`, not `rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - 1]`

Comment: @Adrian I changed it to `sizeof(win32_struct::data)` now

Comment: Um, not quite correct either.  It is a member variable not a static member variable, so the syntax for what you are trying to do would be `sizeof(std::declval<win32_struct>().data)`.  In any case, this still doesn't work.  As I said before, the `data` and `rest_of_data` are not in contiguous addresses.  There's padding in between.

Comment: Good that you are trying not to  assume the size of the extension char though.

Comment: @Adrian: <sigh> `char rest_of_data[DATA_SIZE - (sizeof(win32_struct) - offsetof(win32_struct, data))];` takes alignment padding after `win32_struct::data` into account so the total `DATA_SIZE` consists of `win32_struct::data + padding + my_struct::rest_of_data`.

Comment: Yes, I've been down this route before too.  What would happen if `DATA_SIZE` is 3?  And even though you compensated for the padding, it still doesn't answer the original question.  Also note that even though I wrote an answer, I'm not even going to accept that because it is also a workaround, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Adrian: how does this not answer the original question? If you specify `DATA_SIZE=3`, but the alignment padding is 2+, `rest_of_data` would have a size of 0 or even negative, which is undefined behavior, or at least a compiler error. You have to have SOME knowledge about the total size of `win32_struct` when specifying a value for `DATA_SIZE` so `rest_of_data` can be 1+ bytes in size. Otherwise, use `static_assert()` to ensure `DATA_SIZE` is not too small.

Comment: Allowing `DATA_SIZE` to be less than a valid size is a bad idea in general.  Even if the structure is known, it shouldn't be allowed to put it into that state.  This, of course could be stopped with a `static_assert` and stating that such a value is invald because... yada yada yada. 
 Yet, your answer still doesn't answer the question of `How to align derived class members such that the first member comes immediately after the last member of the base class?`.  You are simply working around the problem not answering the question.

Comment: I did address that question, actually. By setting the alignment of `my_struct` to 1, `base` and `rest_of_data` are right up against each other without any padding between them. But the issue is that `win32_struct` itself may have its own inner padding after its `data` member, to align its total size to an even multiple of its alignment, and nothing you can do in your own code can change that size. Win32 API structs have a specific alignment at the OS layer, you can't change their alignments. So, all you can do is include that inner padding in your `DATA_SIZE` calculation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best I can do is to use a template struct with an anonymous union containing the old type and an anonymous struct with padding and the actual data.

```
template <typename OLD_T, size_t DATA_START, size_t SIZE>
struct new_t
{
    union
    {
        OLD_T internal;
        struct
        {
            char  __declspec(align(1)) padding[DATA_START];
            char  __declspec(align(1)) extended_data[SIZE];
        };
    };

    operator OLD_T&() { return internal; }
    OLD_T* operator&() { return &internal; }
};

new_t<old_t, offsetof(old_t, data), 5> object_with_5_char_array_at_end;
```

Here, `extended_data` is actually placed at the same location as `data`.  I could have placed it after it to answer this question as asked, but the anonymous struct really isn't used anyway, so I went with cleaner calculations.

This doesn't use the `#pragma pack` so that the entire struct can be properly aligned for speed.  It's unfortunate that I have to have a level of indirection to access the original object, but at least I can define the conversion operator so I can at least pass this as if it was the original object type and addressof operator so I can get the address of the original type as the original type pointer.

Too bad a union couldn't inherit from a struct to remove the extra layer of indirection.  Of course that could open up a whole other can of worms. :)